# JavaScript access issue in winforms webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, .net, winforms, security, browser

**ETA: I've got it working and the answer is posted below. I'll mark as the answer anyone who can explain exactly what is going on and how I can clean it up.**

I have a class that contains a form with a winforms webbrowser control to display an html page. I inject some script into the head of the page so that I can query information about styles.

When I launch the app from an executable, everything works fine. However I'm now attempting to launch the app from an add-in at design-time. What happens is you right-click on a .htm type file and click to launch the browser. The add-in then launches the browser which navigates to the supplied .htm file path.

The first thing I notice is that the browser now displays this message:

"*To help protect your security, your web browser has restricted this file from showing active content that could access your computer. Click here for options...*"

I then noticed that all my javascript calls were now failing even if I clicked to enable active content.

As a test I tried this simple javascript call (without explicit injection):

```
Me.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", New Object() {"alert('hello');", "JavaScript"})
```

This results in a javascript error dialog that says "*access is denied*"

So, this is a security issue. Not that I wanted to but, I tried temporarily reducing all security levels in IE but this made no difference.

I should add that the app contains 2 webbrowser controls. The second one hosts a web page that is created by setting the *DocumentText* property of the browser. This does not suffer from javascript access issues.

ETA: I've been looking into IInternetSecurityManager, could it be anything to do with that? I hope not :(

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get it working with IInternetSecurityManager which is a service that is returned by the webbrowser control's site.
I got it working by returning Ok in the ProcessUrlAction method regardless of the url.

I cribbed this together from bits I found on the internet so if anyone can point out how it can be cleaned up and restricted to the intranet then i'll mark that as the answer.

I presume i need to examine the url, in ProcessUrlAction, and return Ok, or Default depending on its content.

Here's the code:

```
Friend Class MainBrowser
Inherits WebBrowser

Private _Site As WebBrowserSite
Protected Overrides Function CreateWebBrowserSiteBase() As WebBrowserSiteBase
    If _Site Is Nothing Then
        _Site = New WebBrowserSite(Me)
    End If
    Return _Site
End Function

Protected Class WebBrowserSite
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite
    Implements NativeInterfaces.IServiceProvider
    Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager

    Private Const INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION As Integer = &H800C0011
    Private Const S_OK As Integer = 0
    Private Const E_NOINTERFACEX As Integer = &H80004002

    Private Shared IID_IInternetSecurityManager As Guid = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(GetType(NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager))

    Private Owner As MainBrowser

    Public Sub New(ByVal owner As MainBrowser)
        MyBase.New(owner)
        owner = owner
    End Sub

    Public Function QueryService(ByRef guidService As System.Guid, ByRef riid As System.Guid, ByRef ppvObject As System.IntPtr) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IServiceProvider.QueryService
        If guidService = IID_IInternetSecurityManager AndAlso riid = IID_IInternetSecurityManager Then
            ppvObject = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(Me, GetType(NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager))
            Return S_OK
        End If
        ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero
        Return E_NOINTERFACEX
    End Function

    Public Function GetSecurityId(ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByVal pbSecurityId As System.IntPtr, ByRef pcbSecurityId As UInteger, ByRef dwReserved As UInteger) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.GetSecurityId
        Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

    Public Function GetSecuritySite(ByRef pSite As System.IntPtr) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.GetSecuritySite
        pSite = IntPtr.Zero
        Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

    Public Function SetSecuritySite(ByVal pSite As System.IntPtr) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.SetSecuritySite
        Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

    Public Function MapUrlToZone(ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByRef pdwZone As UInteger, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.MapUrlToZone
        pdwZone = 0 // URLZONE_LOCAL_MACHINE ?
        Return S_OK // no difference
        // Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

    Public Function ProcessUrlAction(ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByVal dwAction As UInteger, ByVal pPolicy As System.IntPtr, ByVal cbPolicy As UInteger, ByVal pContext As System.IntPtr, ByVal cbContext As UInteger, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger, ByVal dwReserved As UInteger) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.ProcessUrlAction
        // Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
        Return S_OK // This is what made the difference
    End Function

    Public Function QueryCustomPolicy(ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByRef guidKey As System.Guid, ByRef ppPolicy As System.IntPtr, ByRef pcbPolicy As UInteger, ByVal pContext As System.IntPtr, ByVal cbContext As UInteger, ByVal dwReserved As UInteger) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.QueryCustomPolicy
        ppPolicy = IntPtr.Zero
        pcbPolicy = 0
        Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

    Public Function SetZoneMapping1(ByVal dwZone As UInteger, ByVal lpszPattern As String, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.SetZoneMapping
        Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

    Public Function GetZoneMappings(ByVal dwZone As UInteger, ByRef ppenumString As System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumString, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer Implements NativeInterfaces.IInternetSecurityManager.GetZoneMappings
        ppenumString = Nothing
        Return INET_E_DEFAULT_ACTION
    End Function

End Class

End Class
```

**The Interfaces:**

```
 <ComImport(), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")> _
Interface IServiceProvider
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function QueryService(ByRef guidService As Guid, ByRef riid As Guid, ByRef ppvObject As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer
End Interface


<ComImport(), GuidAttribute("79EAC9EE-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B"), InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface IInternetSecurityManager
    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function SetSecuritySite(<[In]()> ByVal pSite As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function GetSecuritySite(ByRef pSite As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function MapUrlToZone(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByRef pdwZone As UInt32, <[In]()> ByVal dwFlags As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function GetSecurityId(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pwszUrl As String, <Out()> ByVal pbSecurityId As IntPtr, <[In](), Out()> ByRef pcbSecurityId As UInt32, <[In]()> ByRef dwReserved As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function ProcessUrlAction(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByVal dwAction As UInt32, ByVal pPolicy As IntPtr, ByVal cbPolicy As UInt32, ByVal pContext As IntPtr, ByVal cbContext As UInt32, _
         ByVal dwFlags As UInt32, ByVal dwReserved As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function QueryCustomPolicy(<[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pwszUrl As String, ByRef guidKey As Guid, ByRef ppPolicy As IntPtr, ByRef pcbPolicy As UInt32, ByVal pContext As IntPtr, ByVal cbContext As UInt32, _
         ByVal dwReserved As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function SetZoneMapping(ByVal dwZone As UInt32, <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lpszPattern As String, ByVal dwFlags As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer

    <PreserveSig()> _
    Function GetZoneMappings(<[In]()> ByVal dwZone As UInt32, ByRef ppenumString As ComTypes.IEnumString, <[In]()> ByVal dwFlags As UInt32) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)> Integer
End Interface
```